# How to implement a "read more" style button at the end of a text in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a very long text and I want to show just 3 lines with **more** button just like the picture and also a less button when the text is expand. Any idea of how to do it with SwiftUI?

[image]

```
var body: some View{
    VStack{
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
    }
}
```

Comment: See update please

Comment: Have you considered using a `Button` in an `.overlay` view modifier that is applied to your `Text` view?

Comment: Could you please use the code to show me ?

Answer (score 4):

You can read this [Medium](https://prafullkumar77.medium.com/swiftui-how-to-make-see-more-see-less-style-button-at-the-end-of-text-675f859c2c4f) article

```
struct ExpandableText: View {
    
    @State private var expanded: Bool = false
    @State private var truncated: Bool = false
    @State private var shrinkText: String
    
    private var text: String
    let font: UIFont
    let lineLimit: Int
    
    init(_ text: String, lineLimit: Int, font: UIFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)) {
        self.text = text
        _shrinkText =  State(wrappedValue: text)
        self.lineLimit = lineLimit
        self.font = font
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
            Group {
                Text(self.expanded ? text : shrinkText) + Text(moreLessText)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: false)
            .lineLimit(expanded ? nil : lineLimit)
            .background(
                // Render the limited text and measure its size
                Text(text)
                    .lineLimit(lineLimit)
                    .background(GeometryReader { visibleTextGeometry in
                        Color.clear.onAppear() {
                            let size = CGSize(width: visibleTextGeometry.size.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
                            let attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key:Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]

                            ///Binary search until mid == low && mid == high
                            var low  = 0
                            var heigh = shrinkText.count
                            var mid = heigh ///start from top so that if text contain we does not need to loop
                            ///
                            while ((heigh - low) > 1) {
                                let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: shrinkText + moreLessText, attributes: attributes)
                                let boundingRect = attributedText.boundingRect(with: size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
                                if boundingRect.size.height > visibleTextGeometry.size.height {
                                    truncated = true
                                    heigh = mid
                                    mid = (heigh + low)/2
                                    
                                } else {
                                    if mid == text.count {
                                        break
                                    } else {
                                        low = mid
                                        mid = (low + heigh)/2
                                    }
                                }
                                shrinkText = String(text.prefix(mid))
                            }
                            
                            if truncated {
                                shrinkText = String(shrinkText.prefix(shrinkText.count - 2))  //-2 extra as highlighted text is bold
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .hidden() // Hide the background
            )
            .font(Font(font)) ///set default font
            ///
            if truncated {
                Button(action: {
                    expanded.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    HStack { //taking tap on only last line, As it is not possible to get 'see more' location
                        Spacer()
                        Text("")
                    }.opacity(0)
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var moreLessText: String {
        if !truncated {
            return ""
        } else {
            return self.expanded ? " read less" : " ... read more"
        }
    }
    
}
```

And use this ExpandableText in your view like bellow

```
ExpandableText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut laborum", lineLimit: 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit of a hack, because it does not truncate the actual string and apply the "..." suffix, which in my humble opinion would be the better engineered solution. That would require the programmer to determine the length of the string that fits within three lines, remove the last two words (to allow for the More/Less button) and apply the "..." suffix.

This solution limits the number of lines shown and literally covers the trailing end of the third line with a white background and the button. But it may be suitable for your case...

```
@State private var isExpanded: Bool = false

var body: some View{
    
    VStack{

        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
            .lineLimit(isExpanded ? nil : 3)
            .overlay(
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Button(action: {
                        isExpanded.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text(isExpanded ? "Less" : "More")
                            .font(.caption).bold()
                            .padding(.leading, 8.0)
                            .padding(.top, 4.0)
                            .background(Color.white)
                    }
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                }
            )
    }
}
```

You can learn how to do this by following Apple's "[Introducing SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/)" tutorials. Specifically the "Creating a macOS app" tutorial, "[Section 9 Build the Detail View](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-macos-app#Build-the-Detail-View)".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Actually it worked but if I make the text a little bit longer it doesn't show the integral text

Comment: When I add fixedSize to the Text("") the whole text appear but does'nt scroll . It seems like somethink block it from scrolling up or down

Comment: Depending on the software you’re using, you might experience problems attempting to use `.fixedSize` modifier - it does not function as expected. Let Apple know by filing a Feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to achieve the similar Results as you. Also spent hours finding the solution when it was in front of me all along...!

The solution is to use ZStack along with ScrollView and GeometaryReader all at once...

```
struct CollapsableTextView: View {
    let lineLimit: Int
    
    @State private var expanded: Bool = false
    @State private var showViewButton: Bool = false
    private var text: String
    
    init(_ text: String, lineLimit: Int) {
        self.text = text
        self.lineLimit = lineLimit
        
    }
    
    private var moreLessText: String {
        if showViewButton {
            return expanded ? "View Less" : "View More"
            
        } else {
            return ""
            
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ZStack {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.body)
                    .lineLimit(expanded ? nil : lineLimit)
                
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    Text(text)
                        .font(.body)
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { proxy in
                                Color.clear
                                    .onAppear {
                                        showViewButton = proxy.size.height > CGFloat(22 * lineLimit)
                                    }
                                    .onChange(of: text) { _ in
                                        showViewButton = proxy.size.height > CGFloat(22 * lineLimit)
                                    }
                            }
                        )
                    
                }
                .opacity(0.0)
                .disabled(true)
                .frame(height: 0.0)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    expanded.toggle()
                }
            }, label: {
                Text(moreLessText)
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
            })
            .opacity(showViewButton ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            .disabled(!showViewButton)
            .frame(height: showViewButton ? nil : 0.0)
            
        }
    }
}

struct CollapsableTextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CollapsableTextView("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.", lineLimit: 3)
    }
    
}
```

The Most important part of this code is `CGFloat(22 * lineLimit)` here 22 is the height of single Line with the specified font used. You might have to change the height (i.e. 22 in this case) based upon your font...

Other than that every thing is pretty straight forward. I hope it might help...!